# In Sinatra, is there a way to forward a request to another app?

Tags: sinatra, rack

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class Dispatcher < Sinatra::Base
  def initialize
    @foo = Foo.new
  end

  get '/foo/*' do 
    @foo.call(params[:splat])
  end
end
```

So that URL /foo/abc/def?xxx=yyy would be like calling the Foo app with /abc/def?xxx=yyy.

This seems like it should be easy, but I haven't seen any example of it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this in a Rack config.ru file:

```
map "/abc" do
  run Foo.new('abc')
end

map "/def" do
  run Foo.new('def')
end
```

Not exactly what I wanted, but saves me from modifying the underlying app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would use Sinatra for that. If I understand you right, and you use Apache with Proxy-Rewrite rules you just do:

**The .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*) http://localhost:61000/$1 [P]
```

So all your `domain.tdl/foo` get redirected to your local running app at`http://localhost:61000/` with all Post and Get Parameters.

Comment: I was trying to avoid shoving that in Apache. Basically, I have an app that I need to run 3-10 instances with slightly different config, and I didn't want to run one Vegas process for each.