# Rack apps mounted in different subdomains

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, ruby-grape

I'm building a Grape API alongside Sinatra. So far I've been mounting them in separate routes like this:

```
run Rack::URLMap.new("/" => Frontend::Server.new,
                     "/api" => API::Server.new)
```

Where the "/api" is served by a Grape app and "/" by a Sinatra app. But I wanted to use subdomains to separate those concerns instead of the actual "sub-URL". Any clues on how to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19591172/1279355 this is may an other solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [rack-subdomain](https://github.com/mattt/rack-subdomain) gem, but it only handles redirection to paths, not rack apps. You could fork it and make it redirect to rack apps instead.

You could also just roll your own :

```
class SubdomainDispatcher
  def initialize
    @frontend = Frontend::Server.new
    @api      = API::Server.new
  end

  def call(env)
    if subdomain == 'api'
      return @api.call(env)
    else
      return @frontend.call(env)
    end
  end

  private

  # If may be more robust to use a 3rd party plugin to extract the subdomain
  # e.g ActionDispatch::Http::URL.extract_subdomain(@env['HTTP_HOST'])
  def subdomain
    @env['HTTP_HOST'].split('.').first
  end
end


run SubdomainDispatcher.new
```